# jQuery: Single change event to fire multiple functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm systematically building jQuery functions such that the css classes of various inputs in a web form have dependencies on other inputs (i.e. when a given input has a given value, the "hide" class is removed from the appropriate subsequent input etc.)

A specific (working) example of the jQuery I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
    $("input[name$='q_4']").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'Yes') {
             $('#qu_5').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
             $('#qu_5').addClass('hide');
        }
    });             
});
```

In this example, the dependent question div (#qu_5) depends on the value entered via radio button for (name=q_4) to be "Yes".

Because I am building these functions dynamically (users can edit properties of questions such that they have these kinds of display dependencies) via a database, I end up with multiple chunks of this code on a page with several interdependent inputs. Each chunk of code has the name of the master question, the id of the slave question and the value that the slave relies on to be revealed. This also works as intended.

Sometimes however, one input should reveal multiple other questions so I end up with code something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
    $("input[name$='q_87']").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes') {
             $('#qu_88').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
             $('#qu_88').addClass('hide');
        }
    });                 

    $("input[name$='q_87']").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes') {
             $('#qu_89').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
             $('#qu_89').addClass('hide');
        }
    });                     
});
```

This does not work. (and indeed stops all the reveal / hide functions working on that page)

I presume it is because jQuery/javascript isn't happy with the same event `input[name$='q_87']").change` firing two different functions? This is the only thing I can think of.

Does anyone have any advice as to how I could achieve what I want in a way that works? Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you not use classes and data attributes to create a generic function to do this for you, instead of having N+1 event unique handlers for every field?

Comment: @tymeJV I think it's to do with the way the functions are built dynamically - presumably making your suggestion difficult?

Comment: $("input[name$='q_87']").change(function(){
  $('#qu_88, #qu_89').toggleClass('hide',this.value == 'yes');
});

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan perhaps, but I can't think how to do this given that I'm building them one at a time based on user specifications. I guess there might be a way to completely re think my approach...

Comment: Can you add attributes to the elements that need to be hidden/show?  If so, you could add something like `data-input="q_87"` on all the elements that need to be toggled by a change on that input.  You could then make a generic function to attach to all the elements, rather than making a change function for each of them individually.

Comment: My suggestion can take an array: `$("input[name$='"+someVar+"']").change(function(){ $("'"+someArray+"'").toggleClass('hide',this.value == 'yes'); });`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! I'm just working on adapting that now I think it will solve my issue - if you write it as an answer I could accept it if it works out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a var and an array you can write it like this

```
var questions = {
  "q_87":["qu_88","qu_89"],
  "q_96":["qu_95","qu_99"]
}


$.each(questions,function(q,arr) {
  $("input[name$='"+q+"']").change(function(){    
    $("'#"+arr.join(",#")+"'").toggleClass('hide',this.value == 'yes'); 
  });
});
```